# "File/Directory is not readable" when copying content to S3 bucket from Jenkins slave

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, yaml

When I **copy the file from the Jenkins slave to the s3 bucket** I get the error that the **File or Directory is not readable**.
I checked the permission of the file and found that the file has the **owner and group both set as root**. I think this might be an issue because of which the file is not readable by the Jenkins slave. The other files could be easily be uploaded as they have the user and group set to jenkin user.

I think the above is the root cause of the issue but there could be other reasons as well. In order to resolve the issue I tried to change the permission of the file using chmod command but the **slave has no permission to change the permissions of the file**.
`chmod 777 FileName` fails

[image]

Is there any other way to change the permission of the file or any other workaround to get this file pushed to s3 bucket.

**Note:**

- Chmod 777 fails (with and without sudo both fails)
- cat command on file fails

Comment: Can you explain how you deploy the Jenkins agent on your machine? By using Docker or installing it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Run this.
sudo chown -R jenkins-slave. yourfile.yaml